# What is .phpunit.result.cache

Tags: php, laravel, unit-testing, laravel-5, phpunit

When I run tests with **PhpUnit** on a new package I'm creating for Laravel, it generates the file `.phpunit.result.cache`.

What to do with that? Do I add it to my `.gitignore` file or not?

I'm using PHPUnit 8.0.4

Answer (score 82, accepted):

This file helps PHPUnit remember which tests previously failed, which can speed up your testing flow if you only re-run failed tests during development. This is useful for test-driven workflows in which you have configured tests to run automatically, such as on file save, and the same collection of tests is being run repeatedly.

> It is also a good idea to add the cache file .phpunit.result.cache to
> your .gitignore so that it does not end up being committed to your
> repository.
>
> https://laravel-news.com/tips-to-speed-up-phpunit-tests

If you would prefer not to generate the file then you can run phpunit with the `--do-not-cache-result` option, as pointed out by @Slack Undertow in the comments. This might be desired when running tests as part of a build pipeline, for example. Or, as @codekandis pointed out, the same option is available as the `cacheResult` attribute in `phpunit.xml`.

Comment: @SlackUndertow https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/issues/3587#issuecomment-480181912

"[...] Basically the cache is to speed up when testing _the same_ collection over and over again [...]" So a decision to turn it of should be made by the test collection size and the assumed iterations of testing that collection.

But: "[...] When using the play / pause buttons in PHPStorm for example, caching this result makes no sense. In addition to the IDE having its own 'run failed tests again/first' option. [...]" The cache is mainly useful in non-IDE environments.

Answer (score 22):

You can also change this file location by editing `phpunit.xml`:

```
<phpunit 
    ...
    cacheResultFile="../.temp/fs_cache/.phpunit.result.cache"
>
```

Or completely disable it by

```
<phpunit 
    ...
    cacheResult ="false"
>
```

Answer (score 3):

[Official PHPUnit explanation](https://phpunit.readthedocs.io/en/9.5/configuration.html?highlight=caching#the-cacheresult-attribute) (I currently don't find [any other](https://phpunit.readthedocs.io/en/9.5/search.html?q=cache&check_keywords=yes&area=default#) useful official details).

> This caching is required for certain other features to work.

You can disable it with:

```
<phpunit 
    ...
    cacheResult="false">
```